# What is the benefit of Rest Parameter over array type parameter?

Tags: javascript

Is there any particular use case which can only be achieved by using Rest parameter instead of using an array type parameter?

```js
function add1(...args) {
  let result = 0;

  for (let arg of args) result += arg;

  return result
}

function add2(args) {
  let result = 0;

  for (let arg of args) result += arg;

  return result
}

console.log(add1(1,2,3)); // 6
console.log(add2([1,2,3])); // 6
```

Comment: Depends on your use case. With rest you could get first parameter separately and collect the remaining parameters to a collection: Eg: `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass the argument as an array-like object or iterable then you can use the array as input, If you wish to use the elements as the arguments then you have to use the rest parameter.

The downside of using the first method is some array methods only support iterable. So you have to go for custom made function.

It depends on the function arguments. Let's take `Math.max` as an example.

```
const numbers = [1, 3, 4]

Math.max(numbers) //output will be NaN

Math.max(...numbers) //output will be 4. More convenient than passing an array to the function on integers
```